# How to find Apache 2.4 `systemd_module` explanation?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

After several days test, I found a problem:
`LoadModule systemd_module modules/mod_systemd.so` is necessary when Apache 2.4.6 start in centos 7.4
Without `LoadModule systemd_module modules/mod_systemd.so` , Apache will `httpd.service start operation timed out. Terminating.`

Then, I check [apache 2.4 modules list](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/#S), there's no any module named `systemd`.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess (I don't have access to a CentOS system at the moment)  is that Red Hat ["backported"](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting)  the systemd functionality from the development branch of Apache httpd and included it in the Apache httpd 2.4 version they ship and support.
You can probably find when and how in the package Change Log with `rpm -q --changelog httpd` or in the source RPM.

The documentation for the systemd module is therefore found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_systemd.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is backported from the development branch. Sources and history for the module can be found at [1](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/arch/unix/mod_systemd.c). It is usually patched into Fedora and CentOS rpms, see for example [2](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/httpd/blob/master/f/httpd-2.4.33-systemd.patch).